# Elegant way to display comma-separated integers in the frontend and taking it as non-comma-separated in the backend ( preferably using Python/Django )

Tags: jquery, python, django

In my line of work, I wrote custom accounting software in Web-Application form, which means that I deal a lot of numbers. Where I am located ( Indonesia ), our currency is big, 13000 Rupiah is equals to 1 USD. Needless to say, I want to know if there is an elegant solution to display a comma separated integer as the user type a value in the input field AND then parsing it out after submitting it to the backend.

I have used the autonumeric plugin before ( http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin ), and parse it in the backend after submitting the form.

However, is there an easier way ( or more elegant ) way?

Thank you in advance!

---

Here's a bit more details on what I tried

Here's my template:

```
`{% load humanize %}` 
`{{ form.value|bootstrap|intcomma }}`
```

And my model: 
    `value = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)`

The generated Html:
    `<input class=" form-control" id="id_value" max="9223372036854775807"     min="-9223372036854775808" name="value" type="number">`

Since there's that type="number", I am unable to see the commas in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in DB as normal numbers and use filters to represent them in templates however you want.

Filter for you can be found in `humanize` and it's called [intcomma](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma)

Here is how it works:

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ value|intcomma }}
```

If the value is `42000`, in the front-end you will see `42,000`